# Compare multiple frames with 1 frame

Tags: image, matlab, loops, image-processing

I'm trying to make a script so that I can compare multiple frames to a background frame.  My script is the following:

```
close all
clear all
clc

A=imread('background.jpg');       
coords = [imread('*.jpg')];

numImages = size(coords,1);
images = cell(1,numImages);
data = cell(1, numImages);
for ii = 1 : numImages
    images{ii} = imabsdiff(A,coords(ii,:));
end

for ii = 1 : numImages 
     E= im2bw(images{ii},0.1);
    s = regionprops(E,'centroid');

   data{ii} = reshape([s.Centroid],2,[]).';
end

for ii = 1 : numImages
    csvwrite(sprintf('data%d.csv', ii), data{ii});
end
```

I'm trying to compare the images from `coords` with `A` and then convert them to binary images and get the regionprops into a .csv file. But it doesn't work like I want it to.  `imread` is failing.

Answer (score 0):

[`imread`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/imread.html?searchHighlight=imread) does not understand wild cards.

I would recommend looking at the file exchange for [`glob`](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/40149-expand-wildcards-for-files-and-directory-names), or use matlab's native [`ls`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ls.html?searchHighlight=ls) to deal with wild cards.